How can i make this JavaScript Function work?
I'm currently working on an animation, and I've hit a snag. None of my attempts seem to be working. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
When the user hovers over the added-value-cont, the exit button (exit-btn) should appear.
Here's the code I have so far:


function showExitBtn(added_value_cont, state) {
  if (state === "show") {
    const exit_btn = added_value_cont.querySelector(".exit-btn-hidden");
    exit_btn.classList.remove("exit-btn-hidden");
    exit_btn.classList.add("exit-btn");
  } else if (state === "hide") {
    const exit_btn = added_value_cont.querySelector(".exit-btn");
    exit_btn.classList.remove("exit-btn");
    exit_btn.classList.add("exit-btn-hidden");
  }
}

const added_value_conts = document.getElementsByClassName("added-value-cont");

Array.from(added_value_conts).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    showExitBtn(this, "show");
  });
  element.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    showExitBtn(this, "hide");
  });
});
.added-value-cont,
.added-value {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 5px;
}

.added-value-cont {
  background-color: #202020;
  border-left: 5px solid grey;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.added-value-cont:hover {
  filter: brightness(1.2);
}

.exit-btn-hidden {
  display: none;
  background-color: darkred;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.exit-btn {
  display: block;
  background-color: darkred;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.exit-btn:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.added-value-element {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 5px;
}

.added-value-element:hover {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
<div class="added-value-cont">
  <p id="exit-btn" class="exit-btn-hidden">X</p>
  <div class="added-value">
    <p class="value added-value-element">0.00 €</p>
    <p class="amount added-value-element">0 Stk</p>
    <p class="coin-value added-value-element">(CV: 0.00)</p>
    <p class="gramms added-value-element">(G: 0g)</p>
  </div>
</div>



I appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks in advance!

"None of my attempts seem to be working" - what happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Code appears to be working ok.  Hover over the black on not-quite-as-black text and a red X appears.  What should it be doing?

If your code is doing nothing, then check where your script is in the page.  The snippet that has been create for you puts the js at the bottom of the page. When you loop through, document.getElementsByClassName it will only affect elements that exist at the time the script is running.   Try moving your script to just before </body>.  See this answer for more info.

@fdomn-m
Yes, thank you very much, you helped me a lot. It was indeed because the JavaScript was executed before the page loaded, as I had it in the head. I have now changed it.
Previous import:

Changed import:

With the "defer" parameter, it works.
